# VLC Streams at Higher Sample Rate But Transcodes and Saves to Lower

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming

I am trying to transcode an mpeg4audio stream from a radio station and save the file. I have a headless server I am trying to use `cvlc` with in order to transcode and save the Stream to a file. Here is the command line command I am utilizing:

```bash
/usr/bin/cvlc --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file,mux=mp3,dst=test/test-1-${DATE}.mp3}" https://evanov.leanstream.co/CIDCFM?args=web_01
```

When running the command I get the following output:

```
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[000055baea0d4c30] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[000055bae9ff6290] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[000055baea0d4c30] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007fea54003740] dummy mux: Open
[00007fea543453e0] mpeg4audio demux packetizer: AAC channels: 1 samplerate: 22050
```

However when I use the GUI VLC on my Windows PC and purely stream (no transcoding/saving) I am seeing 2 AAC channels and a sample rate of 44100.

[image: vlc stream codex info]

In the transcoded audio I can confirm the sample rate is 22050 and it also has some weird audio hiccups that are present. This lower sample rate and issues with how the audio sounds is not present when I stream it in VLC GUI. The weird thing is that when I use the VLC GUI wizard to convert the stream to file, it also results in the same lower sample rate, despite the parameters specifying a 44100 sample.

Is there an error in my command here? I am also open to using a different command line program to accomplish this same task. I just want to essentially save this stream in an mp3 format at a similar sounding quality to the original stream.

If it is relevant, the headless server is running Ubuntu 20.04.

Edit:

If I directly hit "Record" in VLC on Windows the stream sounds proper. It is saved as an mp4 file with the audio codec being mp4a (MPEG AAC Audio). 44100 Hz, 32 bits per sample, and AAC extension SBR. Whereas a recording using my command produces a file with a specific bitrate given, and no AAC SBR extension.

See the image below showing a raw recording of the stream with no transcoding on the left, and on the right the audio option recorded with the above `cvlc` command. You can see the differences. I am assuming the issue relates to SBR.

[image: difference between two audio files, proper on the left, broken on the right]

This command will result in an OGG file being generated which sounds correct. So worst case I can just convert the file post-stream recording instead of transcoding live.

```bash
cvlc --sout "#standard{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=test2.ogg" https://evanov.leanstream.co/CIDCFM
```

Comment: try to change codec from mp3 to [vorbis](https://wiki.videolan.org/Vorbis/) in an [ogg](https://wiki.videolan.org/Ogg/) container - it's possible that the mp3 encoder does not handle streamed audio correctly. You can re-encode to mp3 once you have a static file on your machine.

Comment: Try in VLC to open *Tools > Preferences*, click "All" at the bottom, then type above `samplerate` in the search field, and set all of them to the wanted rate or to "High".

Comment: @harrymc I can try that, however I am attempting to do this from the command line and the VLC on Windows example was more just to illustrate that the problem occurs on both VLC on Windows as well as when done via the command line on Ubuntu. So even if this would fix it on Windows, it is not really the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @1NN I'll have to look into this and see how I can alter my command to accomplish what you're suggesting. I have no issue with recording the stream in a different format and then using something like ffmpeg to convert it after the fact. Ultimately it needs to be in mp3, but I am really not concerned with how it gets to that form. Only reason I am doing it this way is because it seemed easiest to just transcode while recording it :).

Comment: The VLC command-line will also obey the Preferences, and not all of them can be set via the command-line.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately I am intending for this to run via a headless server so ultimately I don't have much choice regarding setting the parameters via command line :(

Comment: You might take a different approach : For distros where VLC is installed through their software or package managers, the preferences might be set by just copying their file. [VLC Preferences](https://wiki.videolan.org/Preferences/) mentions `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`, but I have also seen mention of `vlc-qt-interface.conf`.

Comment: @harrymc I don't have any vlc config file that I can find. Likely because I am using it from the command line so there probably is no need for a preferences file.

Comment: Everything you do seems correct. Try maybe using `ab=256`.

Comment: @harrymc That does seem to increase the samplerate to the correct levels. However there is still a very weird audio choppy/stuttering effect going on that you do not hear listening to the stream live without the transcoding/recording.

Comment: I added an answer, for the purpose of the bounty which will soon disappear. `ab=256` might be too large - I've seen `ab=192` used often for audio. You need to keep on juggling the values for finding the optimal combination for your audio.

Comment: @harrymc I can give a shot with fiddling around with the bitrates, but is there no way to allow for a more variable bitrate? I am sure part of the problem here is that the stream itself may be varying the quality/bitrate dynamically. Because I want to note that my original CVLC command was working for years with this radio station, and suddenly around the beginning of December the quality became choppy/stuttery despite no changes on my end. 

Is potentially a better solution to do something like 1NN mentioned in the comments? Just record it in a different format and convert it post-record?

Comment: Some analysis of the source of the problem might help: Try recording other audio sources, try other recording software, check if something changed on your side beginning of December such as a software update, and even launch a query on the VLC forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by recording it as an `ogg` file and then converting it to `mp3`.

The `cvlc` command used to record the stream:

```bash
cvlc --sout "#standard{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=Streams/1035-${DATE}.ogg" https://evanov.leanstream.co/CIDCFM
```

And the `ffmpeg` command to batch convert any .ogg files:

```bash
ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp3" -vn -n -ar 44100 -ac 2 -q:a 2
```

- `-i` - Input file
- `-vn` - Disable video (just in case)
- `-ar 44100` - Audio sampling frequency set to 44100
- `-ac 2` - Audio channels set to 2
- `-q:a 2` - Allows the encoder to pick from 170 to 210 KB/s quality-range (average 192 KB/s)

I referenced a [Stackoverflow answer for this ffmpeg command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952172/1044984).

Overall recording a more "raw" format and converting to `mp3` after seems like it may be the more reliable option than trying to transcode the stream live with VLC to `mp3`.

Answer (score 1):

Raising the target bitrate of the transcoded audio stream, whose
default value is 96, to 256, seems to have increased the samplerate
to the correct levels.

The parameter used was `ab=256`.

There is still an audio choppy/stuttering effect, which might require
trying more combinations and values for `ab` and other parameters.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the bitrate, but see my edit showing an image comparing the "correct" sounding audio file, versus the bad sounding audio files codec. I think I need to figure out how to transcode with the `AAC extension: SBR`. From my understanding this is essentially a variable bitrate?